# How can I set a min-height (or equivalent) when using a angular material column layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have code similar to the following...

```
md-content.body#scroll-area(flex, layout-padding, layout="column")
  df-section-1
  df-section-2
  df-section-3
```

I want to ensure all sections have a minimum height of the parent height. This would allow me to create a scroll-able area where each section is a full page regardless.

Comment: Do you have some javascript? You could solve this with a directive.

Comment: I am inside a directive so I can assign variables as necessary. Do I need use something like Waypoint and track scroll position?

Comment: Please provide some code (the directive js) and html.